# Converting xls files to json with xlsx.js - issue with hyperlink

Tags: javascript, js-xlsx

I use the xlsx.js library for converting excel-files to json and it works, but I have a problem when I add a hyperlink into a cell of the table as it's illustrated in the image below:

[image]

The code I use for parsing:

```
    function readExcel(url) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    if (xmlhttp.overrideMimeType) {
        xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    }
    xmlhttp.onload = function(e) {
        var arraybuffer = xmlhttp.response;
        var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
        var arr = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        var wb = XLSX.read(arr.join(""), { type: "binary" });
       
       // var sheet_name_list = wb.SheetNames;
        wb.SheetNames.forEach((sheetName, index) => {
            let jsonObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[sheetName], { header: 1, raw: true })
            console.log("jsonObject", jsonObject)
            createTable(jsonObject, index);
        });
        
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The current output:

```
[
    [
        "FirstName",
        "LastName",
        "Age",
        "Country"
    ],
    [
        "Alessio",
        "",
        23,
        "Italia"
    ],
    [
        "Mauro",
        "Doe",
        34,
        "Germania"
    ],
    ...............
]
```

The problem is on Germania the hyperlink isn't present - How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect that instead of using `sheet_to_json()`, you'll need to write a custom variant of that function that will also use the `cell.l` (hyperlink) property. Check [here](https://docs.sheetjs.com/#cell-object) and search for `hyperlink`.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! The `xlsx` library doesn't seem to support this out of the box, but luckily it does provide a very simplistic structure of the sheet that we can interact with before converting to JSON.

The structure of each cell object is based on its content, all possible cell properties can be found in the [Cell Object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#cell-object) section of the `xlsx` documentation.

In the documentation, we can see that hyperlinks are stored in the `l` key of the cell object.

To access this, we need to do so before converting the sheet data to JSON.

In your original question, the workbook object can be found at `wb.Sheets[sheetName]`. If we log this value out prior to converting it to JSON, it would look something like this:

```js
{
  '!ref': 'A1:D5',
  A1: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'FirstName',
    r: '<t>FirstName</t>',
    h: 'FirstName',
    w: 'FirstName'
  },
  B1: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'LastName',
    r: '<t>LastName</t>',
    h: 'LastName',
    w: 'LastName'
  },
  C1: { t: 's', v: 'Age', r: '<t>Age</t>', h: 'Age', w: 'Age' },
  D1: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'Country',
    r: '<t>Country</t>',
    h: 'Country',
    w: 'Country'
  },
  A2: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'Alessio',
    r: '<t>Alessio</t>',
    h: 'Alessio',
    w: 'Alessio'
  },
  C2: { t: 'n', v: 23, w: '23' },
  D2: { t: 's', v: 'Italia', r: '<t>Italia</t>', h: 'Italia', w: 'Italia' },
  A3: { t: 's', v: 'Mauro', r: '<t>Mauro</t>', h: 'Mauro', w: 'Mauro' },
  B3: { t: 's', v: 'Doe', r: '<t>Doe</t>', h: 'Doe', w: 'Doe' },
  C3: { t: 'n', v: 34, w: '34' },
  D3: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'Germania',
    r: '<t>Germania</t>',
    h: 'Germania',
    w: 'Germania',
    l: {
      ref: 'D3',
      id: 'rId1',
      uid: '{F50A35D6-56AF-4849-B5E2-A938EFDD7328}',
      Target: 'https://germania.com/',
      Rel: [Object]
    }
  },
  A4: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'Giovanni',
    r: '<t>Giovanni</t>',
    h: 'Giovanni',
    w: 'Giovanni'
  },
  B4: { t: 's', v: 'Zonzo', r: '<t>Zonzo</t>', h: 'Zonzo', w: 'Zonzo' },
  C4: { t: 'n', v: 55, w: '55' },
  D4: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'Polonia',
    r: '<t>Polonia</t>',
    h: 'Polonia',
    w: 'Polonia'
  },
  A5: { t: 's', v: 'Nicola', r: '<t>Nicola</t>', h: 'Nicola', w: 'Nicola' },
  B5: { t: 's', v: 'Fogo', r: '<t>Fogo</t>', h: 'Fogo', w: 'Fogo' },
  C5: { t: 'n', v: 22, w: '22' },
  D5: {
    t: 's',
    v: 'Francia',
    r: '<t>Francia</t>',
    h: 'Francia',
    w: 'Francia'
  },
  '!margins': {
    left: 0.7,
    right: 0.7,
    top: 0.75,
    bottom: 0.75,
    header: 0.3,
    footer: 0.3
  }
}
```

As you can see, in cell `D3` an `l` key is included because the cell is formatted as a hyperlink. The actual hyperlink value can be found inside of `Target` within the `l` object.

Instead of creating our own parser to convert this data to JSON, all we need to do is modify the original workbook object and then convert it to JSON after the fact.

First, we get a list of all of the cells by using `Object.keys()` and then can loop over that list to check if a hyperlink is present or not in the current cell.

```js
const sheet = workbook.Sheets['Sheet1'];

const cells = Object.keys(sheet);
```

If a hyperlink is present, we will overwrite the `v` key inside of the workbook object for that cell which usually represents the `raw` value from the cell.

```js
cells.forEach(cell => {
    // If cell contains a hyperlink, overwrite the raw value with the hyperlink
    if (sheet[cell].l && sheet[cell].l.Target) {
        sheet[cell].v = sheet[cell].l.Target;
    }
});
```

Once we've overwritten the `v` key with the hyperlink values, we can then convert the sheet to JSON like usual.

```js
const json = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, { header: 1, raw: true });
```

Our result should now come out looking something like this:

```js
[
  [ 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Age', 'Country' ],
  [ 'Alessio', null, 23, 'Italia' ],
  [ 'Mauro', 'Doe', 34, 'https://germania.com/' ],
  [ 'Giovanni', 'Zonzo', 55, 'Polonia' ],
  [ 'Nicola', 'Fogo', 22, 'Francia' ]
]
```

Comment: good answer, but if i need both, name and link?

Comment: If you need both, it depends on how you want your end result to be structured. If you simply want to push any hyperlink values over to the next column while preserving the text value, you can just overwrite the `v` key of the sheet object to include the original text. This can be done by changing the content of the `if` statement execution block to include the original text, such as `sheet[cell].v = [ sheet[cell].v, sheet[cell].l.Target ];`. To "push" the hyperlink value to the next column, simply use `.map` to iterate and flatten each of the rows `json.map(row => row.flat());`.